# Rails, multiple has_many to one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `User` and `Job` models. `User` creates multiple `Jobs` that is why I wrote this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This code makes `Users` to have their own `Jobs`. Now I want to make `Users` to have `Jobs` of other users as `favourites`. How it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would make a new model, called favourites, which belongs_to job and belongs_to user. The user and the job would both have_many favourites. The schema would have a USER_ID and a JOB_ID - when you click the favourite button it would link to the create action on the favourites controller and create a new favourite, you would pass the current_user.id into the user_id and the @job.id into the job_id.

Now there is a favourite with the relationship set. So you could call @user.favourites.all in a loop to get the records that user has favourited. You could also call @job.favourites.all and get the favourites for that particular job.

To un-favourite you would just link to the destroy record of that particular favourite

Comment: How to make that own Jobs could not be added to favourites?

Comment: You could set a conditional in the create action, something like 'render :show if @job.user_id == current_user.id' - this would just spit you back to the show page if you tried to favourite your own job... You could then also hide the button in the view using the same kind of conditional, so that the current user can't even see the button